# Unity C# класс не видит переменную другого класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть код `[SerializeField] static GameObject[] InvWeapon { get; set; }`
но не один другой класс его не видит, хотя я назначил аксессоры. Может в unity они не так работают или я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: попробуйте использовать модификатор доступа `public` перед `static`

Comment: В том и прикол, что мне не нужны публичные поля, я для этого добавил аксессоры,  только вот они не работают

Comment: переменную нужно сделать публичной, сеттер и геттер это немного другое

Comment: то есть нельзя передать значение переменной в другой класс без публичного доступа, как в обычном шарпе, даже с get?

Comment: в обычном шарпе?  В `unity` такой же шарп, как и везде. И везде если переменная не публичная, к ней нельзя просто так обратиться

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.2.php

Comment: Блин, точно. У меня были неправильные представления о работе get set. Спасибо всем кто отвечал.

Answer (score 3):

Атрибут `[SerializeField]` дает возможность инициализировать поле *экземпляра* класса через редактор юнити. Экземплярами будут скрипты висящие на разных геймобжектах. *Статические* поля не принадлежат экземплярам, и этот атрибут не произведет на них никакого эффекта, значит и нет смысла вешать его на них. Кроме того, со свойствами атрибут тоже не работает.

Если хотите, чтобы поле было доступно из другого класса, сделайте его `public`, достаньте экземпляр вашего класса и обратитесь к нему. Можете не делать поле публичным, а организовать доступ через свойство. Юнити по умолчанию показывает в редакторе публичные поля, чтобы их скрыть, используйте атрибут `[HideInInspector]`.

Экземпляр вы можете получить через `GetComponent`, если есть экземпляр геймобжекта, или сделайте поле с `[SerializedField]` в другом классе и перетащите туда ваш скрипт в редакторе.